# Listening to serial port on Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, serial-port, port, arduino, usbserial

I am trying to write a program which will listen to the serial input from Arduino board connected via usb, and sending output to serial port (COM4). But I don't know how to get input from serial port in Delphi. I need program to listen to the port, and whenever the input comes, it should react to it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpapro/ is a freeware tool we've used with great success for many years.

Comment: +1 Why was this voted down? It is a wellknown serial lib for Delphi?

Comment: Also works with older versions of Delphi, hurray! +1

Answer (score 5):

The already suggested tpapro will probably also do it, but I myself use [TComport](https://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/), which I consider slightly easier to use. It will has an event property onrxchar that triggers whenever a character arrives (and several options for other kinds of packets, including ASCII linediscipline).

I use it pretty much for the same kind of stuff, albeit with microchips mcus.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the Comport library of WinSoft for many... years. It´s excellent (0 bugs) and works with any version of windows.

The link is: http://www.winsoft.sk/comport.htm